# SQL Server Error - HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a huge 200MB .SQL file. When I try to open this in SQL server management studio 2008, I get the error -Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

What could the reason be and how to fix it ? Is this caused due to big files ? It does not happen when I open a 2-3 KB file.

Comment: Are there any distributed transactions or queries used in the script?

Comment: no, all insert statements.

Comment: @lrb - can you help me to find out the cause and the solution ? Any help would be great.

Comment: This document seems relevant --> http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=170529

Comment: @lrb - one suggestion says use BCP. Can BCP execute my big SQL file ?

Comment: Yes, it can be temperamental but it is better for bulk operations.

Comment: On the other hand you could consider cutting the .sql file into smaller chunks :)

Comment: I got another solution here - http://blog.daringa.com/archives/tag/error-hresult-e_fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component But, I don't know how to make it work. I am figuring it out soon.

Comment: Have you tried running this using `sqlcmd` (i.e. using the command line)? It may handle this better.

Comment: .sql files are intended for loading sets of commands. It sounds like what you are really trying to do is load large amounts of data into the database. You could do this using huge numbers of Select '<data>' UNION statements, but this is not the intended use of these files. You should get back to the original source of this data and get it in a flat file CSV format, or perhaps use another programming language like powershell to process the file into a CSV, that can then be BULK loaded to SQL Server.

Comment: @BillHurt - I wish I could. I am not allowed to do that. So, I am just wondering what else to do.

Comment: @blasto - Not allowed to get another data dumb, or not allowed to process the files into a different format? If you can post some anonymized example rows, and change the question to more of a string manipulation question, you might get help with a script that will re-write your data as a CSV that could be bulk inserted.

Answer (score 6):

please use

sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword -i C:\Database\script.sql

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

Comment: Thanks. For me, I got away with just `sqlcmd -S localhost -i C:\Database\script.sql`.