# Microsoft SQL Server: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, performance-testing

What does this error "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

in SQL Server 2008r2, I create file sample. SQL from SampleDb with Task->Genaret Scrpits,
the file content Data and schema, my file size is **137m**, when I want to open this file, This error was generated.

Please help me to solve.... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is likely due to the size of your SQL Query file.

It may be simplest to find an alternative way to transfer your data, such as using the "Import Data" Wizard. (Right-click on your destination database and select Tasks -> "Import Data.")

Or, if you need to run this Query File, you could try using "sqlcmd" as discussed in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/51ef4b81-6677-4e2d-8b80-648633cf699e/sql-server-management-studio-20052008-what-is-the-largest-sql-file-supported-that-i-can-open?forum=sqltools) and [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647922/sql-server-error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-compone/22496424#22496424).