# Error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component SQL Server in 'new query'

Tags: sql-server

Pressing the key (backspace, home, end, page up, page down, ctrl+space ..) in new query generates an error

> hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

[image]

Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Error - HRESULT E\_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647922/sql-server-error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-compone)

Comment: I'm not trying to open a large file.
I get an exception when I enter a key other than English and numeric keys. (such as home key, end key, pageup key, page down key, backspace key and so on)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL Server as such, it's a problem with SQL Server Management Studio. If you're not using [the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), try that. If you *are* using the latest version, consider filing a bug (after trying this on a separate machine first to exclude the possibility that it's something else in your specific configuration). You are obviously not using the English version, so this might be an internationalization issue.